# LaTeX enforce using long section heads in TOC

Tags: table-of-contents

I am in a situation where I need to use long section headings for the TOC and short section heads for the pdf bookmarks. In the following sample code, the short headings are defined and LaTeX by default uses the short headings for both TOC and bookmarks. I am wondering if it is possible to enforce it to use the long headings for the TOC instead while keeping the short heading for bookmarks?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{Use long header names for TOC}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref} 
\hypersetup{bookmarksdepth=3}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\section[Intro]{Introduction}
text
\section[Short Heading 1]{Long Section Heading 1}
some more text

\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry I haven't well understand *pdf bookmarks*!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `\texorpdfstring` switch:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{Use long header names for TOC}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{bookmarksdepth=3}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\section[Intro]{Introduction}
text
\section{\texorpdfstring{Long Section Heading 1}{Short}}
some more text

\end{document}
```

[image][image]